# What is a continued sequel movie and non continued sequel movie called?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a Non-continued sequel movie vs Continued sequel called?

1.) What i mean by non-continued sequel is that the theme, name of the movie is quite the same, some additional characters may be added, some original character may be deleted. But IMPORTANTLY the lead characters (atleast 2) are different and surely different cast and storyline will not be continual to the original story (one reason is (2 lead) characters are changed).

Example: Movie like (1.) Speed (1994) (2.) Speed 2: Cruise Control (1997)

2.) What i mean by continued sequel is that the theme, name of the movie is the same, some additional characters may be added, some original character may be deleted. But IMPORTANTLY the lead characters (atleast 2) are same and same cast and storyline will be continual or may be different but continual to the original.

Example: Movie like (1.) Spider-Man (2002) (2.) Spider-Man 2 (2004) (3.) Spider-Man 3 (2007)

Comment: While this question is not outside the topic of this site, it is possible that it will get a better answer on the Movies & TV Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'd call that a [franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_series). Stories don't have to connect, only the basic characters. Essentially, a TV **series** is the same, both drama and comedy.

Comment: You often see the phrase "loose sequel" for case 1: see Google.

Answer (score -1):

[Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) probably already expects people to know the answer, which is indeed, [franchise](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=franchise) as suggested in comments.

> A general title or concept used for creating or marketing a series of products, typically films or television shows.
> *‘the Harry Potter franchise’*
>
> — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/franchise)

Comment: The question involves three items: **(1)** the term for what the OP provisionally calls 'non-continued sequel', **(2)** the term for what the OP provisionally calls 'continued sequel', **(3)** the term that covers both (1) and (2). *Franchise* seems to be (3). If so, what are (1) and (2)? Should *sequel* be restricted to (2)? Is there a word for (1) that clearly distinguishes it from (2)? Or should, perhaps, *franchise* be used only for (1), which would reopen the question of what (3) is? Or are all these just marketing buzzwords without very definite meaning?

Comment: @jsw29 I suspect the answer to most of those questions, including the last one, is "Yes". If someone disagrees with the above post, they are very welcome to write their own!

Comment: Regardless of what alternative answers somebody may choose to post, it would be useful to have it clarified whether **this** answer is that *franchise* is (3) or that it is (1).

Comment: Franchise refers to a set of films rather than an individual film, but covers both continuing and non-continuing sequels: *Avengers: Endgame* is the (direct/continuing) sequel to *Avengers: Infinity War* within the Marvel/Avengers franchise. In practice, the designation of what is a sequel is largely down to marketing: *Fast and Furious: Hobbs and Shaw* is a spin-off despite continuing a character's story because it's marketed as a spin-off in the Fast and Furious universe, while *Final Destination 2* is a sequel despite a new cast because it's marketed as a direct follow-up.

Comment: A movie that doesn't quite spin off from a franchise but involves a pretty clean break from previous installments is often called a "reboot". Usually many characters are the same but the actors are different.